# How to select month wise data for year from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user table where data is about 20 years old.
I want to fetch month wise data from `CreatedOn` column that is (2014-07-08 17:44:00) and if data is not available for any month then I want 0 for this month

Example

```
Month   data    year
jan      34     2014
feb      56     2014
march    0      2014
apr      23     2014
```

I am using the following query but it's not working:

```
with cte(monno , monname ) as(
select 1, 'Jan' union all 
select 2, 'Feb' union all 
select 3, 'Mar' union all 
select 4, 'Apr' union all 
select 5, 'May' union all 
select 6, 'Jun' union all 
select 7, 'Jul' union all 
select 8, 'Aug' union all 
select 9, 'Sep' union all 
select 10, 'Oct' union all 
select 11, 'Nov' union all 
select 12, 'Dec' 
)

SELECT DISTINCT monname
    ,monno
    ,count(CreatedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(year, CreatedOn),DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedOn))
FROM Contributors_tbl a
RIGHT JOIN cte b ON DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedOn) = b.monno
AND datepart(year, CreatedOn) = 2014
ORDER BY monno
```

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. What's not working ? Do you have an error message ? What is the datatype of the "CreateOn" column ?

Comment: its result is getting unexpected. my data column is `smalldatetime`

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output and what output you are getting. We can not understand by `result is getting unexpected`

Comment: Is the column`data` is the result from `count(CreatedOn) over(partition by datepart(year,CreatedOn),DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedOn))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Way to find Month Number AND Month Name

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempMonth
    (
        MonthNum int,
        MonthNames varchar(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO  #TempMonth 
    SELECT STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm, number, GETDATE())), 2) AS MonthNum, 
    DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(DATEADD(mm, number, GETDATE())), 0) - 1) AS MonthNames
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE (name IS NULL) AND (number BETWEEN 0 AND 11) ORDER BY STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm, number, GETDATE())), 2)


    SELECT * FROM #TempMonth

    select distinct MonthNames,MonthNum,
    count(CreatedOn) over(partition by datepart(year,CreatedOn),DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedOn))
    from Contributors_tbl a 
    right join #TempMonth b on DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedOn) = b.MonthNum and datepart(year,CreatedOn) = 2014
    order by MonthNum

    DROP Table #TempMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
with cte(monno , monname ) as(
select 1, 'Jan' union all 
select 2, 'Feb' union all 
select 3, 'Mar' union all 
select 4, 'Apr' union all 
select 5, 'May' union all 
select 6, 'Jun' union all 
select 7, 'Jul' union all 
select 8, 'Aug' union all 
select 9, 'Sep' union all 
select 10, 'Oct' union all 
select 11, 'Nov' union all 
select 12, 'Dec' 
)
select monname,
monno,
coalesce(cnt,0) as cnt
from cte c
outer apply (
select count(*) as cnt
from Contributors_tbl 
where CreatedOn >= DATEADD(mm,c.monno - 1,'20140101')
And CreatedOn < DATEADD(mm,c.monno,'20140101')
)t
order by monno
```